# Detecting the OS version then recommended to user to install application

Tags: android, web

I have an android mobile application for the product. I want to display a recommendation message when user open website in android device. Recommendation message should be like For better experience install the mobile application. In that message will provide one link which will open Application if already installed or otherwise redirect on the Play store link.

Actually, I don't have any idea and I don't know where to start. Can you please help me.

**Edited:** 
I have uploaded reference image, In Below image, you can see the highlighted area.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think that this is possible by reading the `User Agent`

https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/user-agent#chrome_for_android_user_agent

> If you are parsing user agent strings using regular expressions, the
> following can be used to check against Chrome on Android phones and
> tablets:
>
> **Phone pattern:** 'Android' + 'Chrome/[.0-9]* Mobile'
>
> **Tablet pattern:**
> 'Android' + 'Chrome/[.0-9]* (?!Mobile)'